# Best way to design database for Image Hosting site?

Tags: mysql, database-design, sphinx, database-performance

what is the best way to design database in mysql for Image hosting site which will be less load on server for high traffic sites.

This is going to be READ-Only database.
thats why i am planning on using : **MYISAM database engine with sphinx** for faster full text search.

does sphinx works best with join/union queries ?

**CASE - 1 :**

```
#######Database: image_host##########

/////////////table name : image////////////

id (int)(11) (auto-increment)
hash (varchar)(32)
name (varchar)(255)
og_name (varchar)(255)
size (int)(11)
datetime (datetime)
user_id (int)(11)
nsfw int(1) default 0
verified int(1)  default 0


///////table name : image_categories///////

id (int)(11) (this is from image table)
category_id (int)(3)

///////table name : categories/////////

category_id (int)(3)
category_name (varchar)(255)

///////table name : image_user///////////

id (int)(11) (this is from image table)
user_id (int)(11)

/////////table name : users////////

user_id (int)(11)
username (varchar)(255)
email (varchar)(255)
paswword (varchar)(32)
```

**CASE - 2 :**
putting everything in one table

```
#######Database: image_host##########

/////////////table name : image////////////

id (int)(11) (auto-increment)
hash (varchar)(32)
name (varchar)(255)
og_name (varchar)(255)
size (int)(11)
datetime (datetime)
category_name (varchar)(255)
username (varchar)(255)
email (varchar)(255)
paswword (varchar)(32)
nsfw int(1) default 0
verified int(1)  default 0
```

there will be millions of records as users will upload images. i am looking for performance based solution, as there will be millions of reads per day.
and i am looking to get

image's id,hash,name,datetime,username,email,category,size,nsfw all in one query, is this possible ?

what are your suggestions ? 
Thanks

Comment: If it was me, I'd use an off-the-shelf product for the back-end, like Gallery3 or Coppermine (both of which, I think, use MySQL). I like Gallery3 because it's very customizable - although you do get stuck with some yukky EAV stuff.

Comment: thanks , but i am looking for something custom made.

Comment: Hey, whatever floats your boat ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Real high traffic image hosting CNDs work with origin servers, if you request something on the CDN, the CDN does the same request on the origin server. It's all handled with HTTP headers, they don't even have a database.

In your case, I'd say it depends on many practical things to chose the perfect database structure. I'd make all username and password fields binary.

The more interesting question is, what about replication, sharding, clustering, engines (MyISAM / Aria for FULLTEXT search, InnoDB for references).

Google for *database normalization* because this is very important for the references and integration. Of course you can JOIN these tables. Be careful only with partitioning/sharding or clustering as there are different rules and engines prefered.

Consider other databases for your purpose too, like MongoDB.

If this is critical business, you should consider consulting a database expert.

Comment: +1 for the NoSQL MongoDB if OP goes for the second method of table creation.

Comment: i never heard database on cdn, you mean on cloud ? for fulltext search i am planning on using sphinx, i am planning on using myisam, as this will be only for reading sql data and there wont be any write operation on the db. is mongo db better solution than mysql for huge database ?

Comment: When I first read *Image hosting site which will be less load on server for high traffic sites* - I thought this is exactly what a CDN does. But they don't use databases. They just request once from your server, and then deliver from their's until we revalidate the file or send GIMS or until the caching expires.
I woulda put the login stuff and so on in MySQL InnoDB and the files in NoSQL, document orientated databases are faster in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For me you must use `MyISAM` and it is faster if all data is in a table but if you have images and categories in same table then it will be a mess.
My opiniion is if you have searching with usernames or with categories then it will be faster to have 1 or 2 tables.. not 3 (images and users). If you dont care about searching with categories and usernames then it is better to use 3 tables. Dont not forget `INDEXES`